# How are HTTP verbs sent to the rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Ruby and the Ruby on Rails framework, I've created three links that read from a database, edit a database entry and delete a database entry:

Show:

```
<a href="/inputs/2">Show</a>
```

Edit:

```
<a href="/inputs/2/edit">Edit</a>
```

Destroy:

```
<a href="/inputs/2" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
```

Edit and show are both `GET`s. Delete is a `DELETE`. What I want to clarify is, where are these methods defined? Is it in the link parameter `data-method="delete"`? In that case, where are there no data-methods set for show and edit? Does rails just assume a link with no data-method is a `GET`? And what is the significance of the `rel="nofollow"` parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [nice blog article](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) about how `data-method` attributes are converted into HTTP verbs via Javascript. In short, as you already guessed, the default is `GET` for all requests issued by clicking on a link.

Answer (score 0):

The Rails router recognizes URLs and dispatches them to a controller’s action. It can also generate paths and URLs, avoiding the need to hardcode strings in your views

for more info check [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: I think the OPs question is more related to the client-side which formulates the HTTP request instead of interpretation on the server.